# Default arguments in class method not unique python

Tags: python, class, oop, methods

I am having a problem with default arguments in python classes. It seems that when an argument is not given, the default links to the same object for all instances of a class. Example:

```
class My_class:
    def __init__(self,options=[]):
        self.options = options

class1 = My_class()
class2 = My_class()

class2.options.append('something')
print(class1.options)
```

This would print:

```
['something']
```

How can i make sure each instance of a class will have a unique list for options, instead of a reference to the same object. For example, this is how i could do it:

```
    def __init__(self,options=None):
        if options is None:
            options = []
        self.options = options
```

However, this doesnt feel correct to me. So my questions are if there is a better way to do it, and for someone to explain the initial behaviour to me since i have a clue what is going on, but i don't fully understand why

Comment: That's a classic, and very controversial, Python gotcha. Almost certainly a duplicate.

Comment: @jkm I am very sure that this was already asked before. However, i don't think that makes my question not valid since in the way i phrased it i could not find it, and probably other people will have the same problem.

It is also the reason why i ask for some explanation and not just a solution, because i lack the knowledge and terminology to find this myself.

Comment: @user3053216 cf https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1132941 - and your solution is the canonical one.

Comment: @brunodesthuilliers  Great, the article linked to the top comment explained very clear what happens. Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is one of most common [python gotchas](http://docs.python-guide.org/en/latest/writing/gotchas/#what-does-happen).

> Python’s default arguments
>   are evaluated once when the function is defined, not each time the
>   function is called. This means that if you use a mutable default
>   argument and mutate it, you will and have mutated that object for all
>   future calls to the function as well. Your second variant with None is
>   just fine and is widely used in python.

Answer (score -1):

Both object using same reference to the list I guess, When you assign it is like shallow copy , Try this deepcopy which will create new list for both objects.

```
import copy
class My_class:
    def __init__(self,options=[]):
        self.options = copy.deepcopy(options)

class1 = My_class()
class2 = My_class()

class2.options.append('something')
print(class1.options)
print(class2.options)
```

Comment: wrong. Check about using `[]` as default argument

Comment: But am able to get the desired output. How is it possible then ?

Comment: Using 'None' in the default argument is a better pratice than using []

Comment: "When you assign it is like shallow copy" => plain wrong, it's not "copying" anything at all.

Comment: This is simply wrong. Please, take a look on how Python deals with default arguments. In this case, if you pass options to My_class() instead of empty calls you will see the problem.  
You have a chance to answer this correctly, but do some experimentation, and put the proper reasoning.

Comment: Ok Will do  next time.